# how to use interface to communicate between activity and sqlite databse helper class

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite, interface

I am new to android. Currently I am working on android application which uses sqlitedb as the app user may not have continuous internet connection.

My problem is - There is one `ReportActivity` which shows all data from sqlite in recyclerview.
There is add option which starts `AddReport` Activity. When I add that new report to server, I start on Service which fetch data from server and store to sqlite. And return to Report Activity.
Now I wanted to update my data in `ReportActivity` after sqlite db is updated. I tried using interface but it is giving `nullpointer exception`.
So how I can use interface in that. I don't want to use broadcast receiver.

Comment: Sqlite with android does not give you the ability get notified when the data changes, you need to make use of Room DB with Live data which notifies you whenever you update your DB.

Comment: please share your logic, code, partial snippet so that we can understand better

Answer (score 1):

You can either use `startActivityForResult()` and return an intent to trigger refresh/fetch the data again on `ReportActivity` once you `finish()` the `AddReportActivity`:

**ReportActivity:**

```
public class ReportActivity extends Activity {

  private static final int REQUEST_ADD_REPORT = 1;
  ...
  private void showAddReport() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, AddReportActivity.class);
    startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_ADD_REPORT);
  }

  @Override
  protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_ADD_REPORT &&
         resultCode == ACTIVITY_OK) {
       // trigger refresh
    }
  }
}
```

**AddReportActivity**:

```
public class AddReportActivity extends Activity {
  ...
  private void addReport() {
     // do some logic on adding the report
     setResult(ACTIVITY_OK);
     finish();
  }
}
```

Or you can just override `onResume()` on `ReportActivity` and move the fetching of data from sqlite in there, so every time the activity resumes, it will always get the updated data.

You can refer to [android activity lifecycle](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle) on when the `onResume()` is being called.

Comment: But we don't know when service will update data in sqlite. After update we need to refresh the report activity.

Comment: If that's the case, you can use websocket and listen on it whenever the service updated the data on sqlite.

Comment: @TentenPonce I have the same problem. Which way is better? 1- Update RecyclerView inside onResume(); or use StartActivityForResul? I use SQLite

Comment: it depends on your use case: if you want to keep it updated every time you go to the page with recyclerview, go with onResume(); else if not, then use `startActivityForResult`

In my personal opinion, its better to use `startActivityForResult` since it will avoid calling SQLite again and again every time you go the recycler view, specially if you know when will your database be updated.